# VBA get the last invoice number and save the new invoice

Tags: vba, excel

I have an invoice template sheet in invoice workbook that i want to save some of its fields in an other workbook "Excel data only", sheet "invoices". When creating an invoice i want to get the last invoice number from the "Excel data only", "Invoices" sheet column A and then add 1 to it.

Note that the invoice number has the format ST00001.

After that i want to save the invoice  number in the workbook excel data only with its details: C10,C11 and C12 which represent the total.

I don't know how to do it since i am new in vba this is what i tried to do but not working.

```
Dim v As Workbook
Set v = Workbooks("Excel data only")

Range("I12").Value = v.Sheets("INVOICES").Cells(v.Sheets("INVOICES").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row.Value + 1
```

Comment: Do you mean that if your last invoice is ST00015 you want to return ST00016?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like

```
Dim v As Workbook, cellValue As String
Set v = Workbooks("Excel data only")
With v.Worksheets("INVOICES")
    cellValue = .Range("A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value
End With

ActiveSheet.Range("I12").Value = "ST" & Format$((Right$(cellValue, 5) + 1), "00000")
```

Comment: Good to hear. :-)

Answer (score 0):

`Sub test_1()
Dim v As Workbook, cellValue As String
With Worksheets("sheet2")
    cellValue = .Range("A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value
End With
    ActiveSheet.Range("B13").Value = "" & Format$((Right$(cellValue, 2) + 1), "")
End Sub`

these codes increment by going to last row number, with increment can you write these codes that can search if any number missing in between invoice it should show that also. for example invooice from 1 to 10 and 7 number is missing so instead of last row number increment it should give me missing number.

thnx